# Grabbing data from XML document on a fairly regular basis on mobile, is it ok for performance?

Tags: iphone, android, windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, linq-to-xml

A game I"m working on has several XML files it uses to manage sprite animations. Currently when I create an instance of a sprite I load it up into an XDocument once and keep it in a cache so that if I need to load it again I can just grab what is arlready in memory.

I do this very often in-game as I create animated sprites and such, going through its definitions like so:

```
var definitions = doc.Document.Descendants(name);
foreach (var animationDefinition in definitions)
```

So my question is, is this acceptable on a mobile phone? Say iPhone 3GS/iPhone 4/Windows Phone 7/Android? I use MonoTouch in ANdroid and iPhone while WP7 has its own .Net running.

The reason I ask is currently I don't load that many animated sprites up but as I do more and more I'm worried it will start hurting performance. I figure it might be best to change my design ideas now than wait to suffer at a later date.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you try to load a larger amount of animated sprites, and see what happens? http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply test what's faster (reading it again an again using a SAXParser or storing it in Memory using DOM).

Maybe it also makes sense to save the read data from your XML-File in something like an Array/Vector/Class so you don't need to parse the XML File over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Well in essentially what you are trying to ask is how many is "too many". I would suggest to find a "practical" limit considering performance, you just need to recursively increase the number of sprites and notice when the application slows down. Keep a safety factor of say 1.5 to 3. And there you know. Again you need to consider how many sprites do you have in all to begin with. If all can possibly be kept in memory respect all other specifications, then go for it. Customer's won't mind a slightly longer loading time for games, as long as it is smooth inside. Else just test stuff out.